# Changing permission for splist

Tags: permissions, splist

How can I change the list permission to be read only for all groups in the site? programmatically.

This is my code:

```
   list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = list.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment;
        foreach (SPGroup group in list.ParentWeb.SiteGroups) {
            roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
            list.RoleAssignments.Add(new SPRoleAssignment(group));
            roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
            roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
            list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
        }
            list.Update();
```

but it's not working!, it's adding the read permission to the current permissions, but not removing the old permissions.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to remove first, update the list, then add. Try that and LMK

Comment: so I need to make 2 foreach?

Comment: I think so, give it a try, after RemoveAll, call List.Update, then add and List.Update again.

Comment: it did not work ..

Comment: I was hoping to go from memory. I'm pulling up my code now. I'll answer shortly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet from my code, works great for me. There is no list.Update() after the final line where we add the assignment. I vaguely remember the ResetRoleInheritance was our saving grace with this.

```
   SPRoleDefinition read = web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];
   SPRoleAssignment memberAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
   memberAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(read);
   SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
   list.ResetRoleInheritance();
   list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
   list.Update();
   list.RoleAssignments.Add(memberAssignment);
```

Comment: but don't you break the inheritance for the list?

Comment: 3rd line from the bottom. ;)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your code, I did the same but with looping all over the site groups and giving them permission over the list, now I have each group with read permission along with its default permission, so I have something like:

Approvers: Read,Approve

Comment: here is my code:   `SPRoleDefinition read = list.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
            list.ResetRoleInheritance();
            list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
            list.Update();
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment;
            foreach (SPGroup group in list.ParentWeb.SiteGroups)
            {
                roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
                roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(read);
                list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
            }
            list.Update();`

Comment: it worked with brearoleinheritance(false) as Lgaud said, with ur code

Comment: Oh good, I was just about to ask if you can break false, then readd the groups. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

BreakRoleInheritance(true) breaks inheritance but copies the existing permissions; BreakRoleInheritance(false) will not copy the permissions over.

Comment: now am having an error on this code: 

   `roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
                list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);`

that the group doesn't exist.. anyone can REALLY help me with this, know what's wrong with my code, or how to make all groups have read only on the list?